# If statement Logic flag

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, logic

So I have two If statements and an overloaded function that needs to be used. I can't seem to figure out the logic for how to get this to work as i want it. To make it easier i took out the nonsense of calling the row and all from the datatable.

```
If IsDBNull(zipcode) Then
  CanBeAssigned(county,state,status)
Else
  If CanBeAssigned(zipcode, status) Then 
    ''LOTS OF CODE''
  else 
    ''tiny bit of code''
  end if
End If
```

So this is what i have and i know of a way to make it what i WANT...but that would require me putting the ''LOTS OF CODE'' before the ELSE...and that seems way too much.

Ideally, I want the first IF to check if 'ZipCode' is Null...if it is > it uses the CanBeAssigned(county,state,status) function and then does the ''LOTS OF CODE THAT I DONT WANT TO POST'' ...

...however, if 'ZipCode' is NOT NULL then it uses the CanBeAssigned(zipcode,status) and then proceeds to do the''LOTS OF CODE THAT I DONT WANT TO POST'' .

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Please add a language tag. Could the "lots of code" be refactored to a new method maybe?

Comment: Please indent the code properly, it’s unclear what you actually want to achieve with your code because of the lacking indentation. Likewise, your description is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Flag as boolean

If IsDBNULL(zipcode) Then
  Flag = CanBeAssigned(county,state,status)
else
   Flag = CanBeAssigned(zipcode,status)
 End If

If Flag Then
  "LOTS OF CODE"
Else
 "tiny bit of code"
End If
```

Comment: Please improve your answer; add a bit of explanation besides just 'showing' the code

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the language it is, the logic is very simple. The python snippet will be:

```
if isDBNULL(ZipCode):
    CanBeAssigned(county,state,status)
else:
    CanBeAssigned(Zipcode,status)
#LOTS OF CODE
```

Comment: Then put that `lots of code` in a function and call it from wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

According to this....

> Ideally, I want the first IF to check if 'ZipCode' is Null...if it is
>
> > it uses the CanBeAssigned(county,state,status) function and then does the ''LOTS OF CODE THAT I DONT WANT TO POST'' ...
>
> ...however, if 'ZipCode' is NOT NULL then it uses the
>   CanBeAssigned(zipcode,status) and then proceeds to do the''LOTS OF
>   CODE THAT I DONT WANT TO POST

The code block below does exactly that.

```
If IsDBNull(zipcode) Then 
  CanBeAssigned(county,state,status)
Else
  CanBeAssigned(zipcode, status)
End If
''LOTS OF CODE HERE''
```